# How can I solve this differential equation by substitution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question I'm working on asks me to solve a differential equation.  The question gives a "hint" of a substitution that I should use.  After working on it for over an hour with no progress, I looked at the solution, but I *still* don't understand it.  The solution reads:

[image]

I get lost at the "it follows that" part.  I solved for the derivative of u with respect to y:

[image]

and when I substitute both in I get:

[image]

the two 2y pieces on the left cancel leaving:

[image]

and after solving for du/dx I get:

[image]

which is *close* to the solution, in fact the first two terms are exactly right, but why does mine have one more term?  Because of the u on the right side in mine, I cannot integrate, so I cannot complete the problem.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking at $\dfrac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}$ rather than $\dfrac{d\mu}{dx}$.

If $\mu=\dfrac{y^2}{x}$ then

$$\dfrac{d\mu}{dx}=\dfrac{2y}{x}\dfrac{dy}{dx} - \dfrac{y^2}{x^2} = \dfrac{2xy\frac{dy}{dx} - y^2}{x^2} $$

and using the earlier result

$$ \dfrac{d\mu}{dx}= \dfrac{1-x^2+y^2-y^2}{x^2}= \dfrac{1-x^2}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the way things are presented could effectively lead to possible confusion.

If instead, we say : choose a substitution such that $y^2=\mu x$ then $y=\sqrt{\mu x}$, $y'=\frac{x \mu'+\mu}{2 \sqrt{x \mu}}$ then things would be more obvious and, after replacement and simplification, would lead to $$\mu'=\frac 1{x^2}-1$$